# Junit testing with spring boot restcontroller

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am new with Java Spring boot and have created a Restcontroller,repository and the service layer. now I am trying to test the restcontroller with junit and mockito, how should I approach the problem?

```
@RequestMapping("/Heise")
@RestController


private HeiseService heiseService;
public HeiseController(HeiseService heiseService) {
    this.heiseService = heiseService;
}

// return the whole heise data
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Heise> getAllHeise(){
    return heiseService.getAllHeise();
}

// return specific data with given id
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Optional<Heise> getHeiseById(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    return heiseService.getHeiseById(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createHeise(@Valid @RequestBody Heise heise){
    heiseService.save(heise);
};

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteHeiseData (@PathVariable String id){
    heiseService.deleteById(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateHeiseCollectionByID(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Valid @RequestBody Heise heise ) {
    heiseService.save(heise);
   }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#unit-testing, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests

Answer (score 0):

You should in your Controller layer mock the Server layer to implement unit tests. Plus, you may use WebMvcTest configuration to mock your Http Server.

For Example :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // To mock Service Layer
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HeiseController.class) // To mock Your Http Server
public class HeiseControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc heiseRestController; // it will be injected by WebMvcTest context loader

    @MockBean
    private HeiseService heiseService; // the mock service

    @Test
    public void testGetPresentHeiseById(){
        // Mock the getById method of heiseService
        Heise heise = new Heise(3); // heise having id = 3
        Mockito.when(heiseService.getById(3)).thenReturn(Optional.of(heise));

            // Build the request method = GET
            RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/heise", 3); // with id url path = 3

            // Http Response Checking 
            ResultMatcher expextedStatus = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()); // status = 200

            // Controller Test

        heiseController.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(expectedStatus); 

// to test the body of response, you may learn about ModelMapper    
        }
    // your unit tests 
    // @see RequestBuilder to build Http Request
    // @see ResultMatcher to test Http Response
    }
```

Comment: what would be an example unit test for example for Get method? should I add Response entity and consume parameter?

Comment: I will add a brief example.